# How to reload div using d3.js library

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to reload a div create with d3.js?

I have this function in my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  calculateStatic();

  setInterval(function(){
    calculateStatic();
  }, 5000);

});
```

The function call every 5 second but the `div` don't change, my code to create a div is like that

```
  function calculateStatic(){
    var json_url = "....";
      var dataset_text = [ 
          {"sSUSP" : "number of suspended slots", 
          "sRSV" : "number of reserved slots",
          "users" : "number of active users",
          "jPEND" : "number of pending jobs",
          "queues" : "number of active queues",
          "sRUN" : "number of running slots",
          "jRUN" : "number of running jobs",
          "ts": "Current time",
          "sNJOBS" : "total number of active slots"}
       ];
    var final_data = [];

    d3.json(json_url, function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key, value){
        if (key in dataset_text[0]){
          name = dataset_text[0][key]
          final_data.push({name, value});
        }
       });
       d3.select("#resume_data").selectAll("div")
        .data(final_data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "item_table")
        .text(function(d){ return d.name + " : " + d.value})
    });
  }
```

any idea how to change this `div`?

Comment: You are missing the update part totally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysing you code, we can see that `final_data` length is never getting bigger. Thus, this is the problem: when you bind the data like this:

```
d3.select("#resume_data").selectAll("div")
    .data(final_data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
```

You create an "enter" selection. But, when you call the function again, as you already have `<div>`s in `#resume_data` and your bound data is never increasing, your "enter" selection is always empty, and nothing is appended.

The proper solution is, as @Pavel [said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747645/how-to-reload-div-using-d3-js-library#comment68721205_40747645), create a proper "update" selection.

**Lazy solution:**

This is a lazy solution, which I personally don't like at all: remove all the previous divs before appending the new ones:

```
d3.select("#resume_data").selectAll("div").remove();//removing old divs

d3.select("#resume_data").selectAll("div")
    .data(final_data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "item_table")
    .text(function(d){ return d.name + " : " + d.value});
```

Comment: Implementing an "update" selection (which, again, is the **best solution**) requires more code, and I advise you to try to create your own "update" selection (even if it doesn't work) and posting it as a question if you have any problem. Otherwise, it will seem that you want people to write code for you.